# Running metadata script from one file type to another using glob

Tags: python, metadata, glob, gdal

I am new to python and am currently stuck on how to run my metadata script on 2 different file types within a directory. I have calculated statistics for a set of GeoTIFFs and need to take those band statistics and paste them into the metadata for another set of files. 
Basically, I have .tif files with the calculated statistics and I need to paste those statistics into the original source file headers.

I can do this for each individual file using GDAL with the script below, but I'm at a standstill on how to make this work for multiple files and have the data match correctly. I used a for loop bash script but I don't think it matches the correct statistics to each source file header.

Do I need to restructure my script to use for/if statements?

My working script for individual files works with this:

```
import sys
from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst

calculated_files = gdal.Open(*.tif, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
source_files = gdal.Open(*.anotherfiletype, gdalconst.GA_Update)

stats = calculated_files.GetMetadata()
band = calculated_files.GetRasterBand(1)

bandStats = band.GetMetadata()

print('bandStats is set to')
print(bandStats)

source_files.SetMetadata(bandStats, )

del(calculated_files)
del(source_files)
```

I've been messing with this addition using glob and a for loop:

```
import glob
import os

types = ('*.tif', '*.anotherfiletype')
all_files = []
for files in types:
    all_files.extend(glob.glob(files))
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you need. Are you saying that the first script works fine and is able to (for instance) put the metadata from `file1.tiff` onto `file.anotherfiletype`? And you want to do it for all file1, file2, file3, etc? Do the TIFFs and other files have the same name (just different extension)?

Comment: Yes, the first script works fine if I use individual file names, sorry if my question is unclear. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this work for an entire directory of File1 to File2 metadata migration. The file types do not currently have the same naming convention before the extension because they're from 2 different sources. I'm guessing this may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to turn your first script into a function, and then pass in a dictionary that maps what two files go together:

```
def transfer_metadata(tif_file, other_file):
    calculated_files = gdal.Open(tif_file, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
    source_files = gdal.Open(other_file, gdalconst.GA_Update)

    stats = calculated_files.GetMetadata()
    band = calculated_files.GetRasterBand(1)
    bandStats = band.GetMetadata()
    print('bandStats is set to {}'.format(bandStats))

    source_files.SetMetadata(bandStats, )

    # optional because I don't see how you're using stats otherwise?
    return stats

data_dict = {'file1.tif': 'monkey.xml', 
             'file2.tif': 'giraffe.txt',
             'file40.tif': 'kitten.html'
             }
for k, v in data_dict.items():
    # The print will print stats since you're returning them
    # If you don't need stats for anything, delete the return and
    # this print call
    print(transfer_metadata(tif_file=k, other_file=v))
```